# PHP registration form,insert ables in phpmyadmin database - User ISA Admin/Regular member

Tags: sql, database-design

I have a ER diagram made up and it consists of USER Table and within that it is set as 
User ISA admin 
and
User ISA member

Admin and Member tables are both child tables of USER.
I want two usertypes, m for member, a for admin.

ADMIN will have the option to change member to admin in admin panel
**ADMIN** table has: admin ID(PK) and user ID(FK)

**MEMBER** tableconsists of
memID (PK) userID (FK) signupDate lastlogin location, age, bio

**USER** table consists of 
ID (PK) fname lname password usertype email

What I am trying to achieve is..

Guest must register via a form on registration age and must automatically be set as usertype (m) for member.

So because I have it as 
USER ISA member
USER ISA admin

Which is the best way to have registration form? should it be for two tables (user and members) which wouldbe easiest way to achieve this in words? And also can it be explained how I can make sure it is auto set a usertype 'm' for member?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For telling admin vs user, you can just use one column (`user_type`). You can also use the [DEFAULT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-type-defaults.html) in your table schema to handle that.

However, if you'd eventually like a more robust permission system, i'd recommend:

- TABLE `users` - stores user info
- TABLE `permissions` - With (e.g., permission_id, permission_name)
- TABLE `users_to_permissions` - A table to link the two

That way, you can explicitly assign permissions for different things:

`SELECT p.* FROM permissions p WHERE permission_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT permission_id FROM users_to_permissions u2p WHERE u2p.user_id = :user_id`

You can also obviously use JOIN, or whatever fits your use case the best. When in doubt, prefer [normalization](http://agiledata.org/essays/dataNormalization.html) and extensibility over a quick one-column solution.

SqlFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bddba5/2

Comment: I'm only learning so I want to keep it simple for now..
So I want to try set a default and also know how or which to put what fields in registration form, do i insert two 1 table or two tables, im confused how to insert into two on form if so..